# Using a listener to update any View Controller

Tags: swift, listener, viewcontroller

In my iOS app, using swift 3, I have a listener that fires whenever some data changes on my backend database. The listener is there so that the UI can be updated live, but of course I have many view controllers who all would do their own unique UI updates if they were the one currently being displayed.

What could I put in my listener callback to...

1. find out which view controller is currently loaded
2. call that view controller's own specific updateUI function (an instance method defined in the view controller class itself)?

Comment: "but of course I have many view controllers who all would do their own unique UI updates" so why do you need a listener to update any? Just add and remove the observer to each view controller with its specific selector

Comment: I suppose that works. I guess I just wanted my listener to be instantiated once and work for any view controller it encounters. It doesn't really matter so I think I'll just go with your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that each view controller adds itself as an observer in its viewWillAppear method, and removes itself in its viewDidDisappear method.

This way :
1 - each controller can observe only the notifications that are of interest to what is shown in its views
2 - you don't have to have a separate class/object that knows about your list of view controllers, and needs to be updated everytime you change this list